# Comments on test cases are not passed to external bug tracker

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Kiwi Version: 12.0

We successfully integrated Redmine as external bug trackers in Kiwi TCMS.

I.e., if we use `Report bug` to open a bug report, a issue is created in Redmine containing the text of the test case.

But we are missing the comments added by the tester during test run. Instead this text is appended at the end of the Redmine issue description:

> **Actual results:**
>
> `<describe what happened>`

1. Where does this text come from?
2. Why are the comments which should contain the "actual results" not transmitted to Redmine?

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Integrate Redmine as external bug tracker
2. Click `Report bug` on any Test Case during Test Run

**Expected result**

Test Case description and comments of tester are added as issue description in Redmine

**Actual result**

Test Case description is added as issue description in Redmine, but comments of tester are missing.